# Finding correlation between binary and numerical variable in Python

Tags: correlation, python, binary-data, continuous-data

I need to investigate the correlation between a numerical (integers, probably not normally distributed) and a binary (1,0) IV in Python. The dataset has 200 samples and we cannot count on the distribution of the numerical IV to be normal.

I googled and found out that maybe a logistic regression would be good choice, but I am not interested in predictions, only in the "correlation" and I couldn't find out how to extract this information from a Log. regression.

I was considering also the Point Biserial correlation but that assumes normal distribution of the continuous IV (which I can't guarantee and I suppose it is not). Anyway I tried scipy's [pointbiserialr](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pointbiserialr.html) but the output of that function includes a p-value. An example output I got is `PointbiserialrResult(correlation=0.12455029647882072, pvalue=0.07099850817142403)` but I don't know how to interpret said p-value (what does it say or to what Null hypothesis is it related?).

What would be the best way to reason about a correlation in this situation and if for example that point biserial approach is correct, how could I interpret the result?

Comment: As the docs mention: "This function uses a shortcut formula but produces the same result as pearsonr." The p-value signifies the difference between 0

Comment: When you see the link for pearsonr, you will also find "The calculation of the p-value relies on the assumption that each dataset is normally distributed.". Isn that a concern? Anyway what difference between 0? A correlation =0 of the population?

Comment: that is the assumption for the p-value, not the correlation metric; it's just testing if there is correlation of specified value or not.

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.